# Filmed lectures by Hassler Whitney

Tags: ho.history-overview

Are there any filmed lectures by outstanding American mathematician Hassler Whitney, besides the two Einstein Chair lectures below (links updated)?

Old lectures, from the 1940s onwards, would be particularly interesting.

https://www.math.stonybrook.edu/Videos/Einstein/11A-19851105-Whitney.html
https://www.math.stonybrook.edu/Videos/Einstein/11B-19851107-Whitney.html

Comment: The links do not work. Can you fix that?

Comment: @Piotr Hajlasz: links updated.

Comment: Ideally those videos should be saved to the Internet Archive, but I don't know how to initiate such a move.

Comment: @David: Er, just download the files, make yourself an IA account and upload them there? I’m not that clear on the legality of such a move, but then I can’t say I care overmuch (and neither do the IA operators, it seems, unless pressed from the outside).

Comment: @AlexShpilkin I was thinking some WaybackMachine method, but that's probably not how these things work. I've not done this before. Otherwise, random VideoHostingTube site of your choice would suffice if legality were not an issue.

Comment: @DavidRoberts Ah, I see. As far as I know, being on the IAWM doesn’t add any particular legal defences, and the WM unfrequently (if ever) saves videos; but IA > IAWM, in that they will also just host files that people upload (provided they are legal and of general interest), and have a better record at it that a random VideoHostingTube (while letting you download the originals without recompression).

Comment: @DavidRoberts Or I was wrong, it seems. I’ve initiated a crawl of the pages, and it appears that the videos got saved as well. (One just needs to search the IAWM for the unsaved URL, and the option to save it will appear alongside the failure message.) In any case, I’ve also gone ahead and [uploaded the recordings to IA](https://archive.org/details/whitney-1985)... so they’ll remain until someone complains, I guess. Anything more would require tracking down the people responsible.

Comment: @Alex thanks! I was trying to do that, but I couldn't figure out how to actually get it to archive the pages/videos.